# Bayesian Optimization AFTER Feature Selection (R)

Tags: r, optimization, random-forest, bayesian, feature-selection

I'm using a random forest to make predictions. And I've concluded that x2, x15 and x20 are the most important features. So my model is like this:

```
randomForest(formula = y ~ +x2, + x15 + x20,mtry...,size...other parameters)
```

However, I still want to use bayesian optimization to better define the remaining parameters of the randomForest function. The problem is that I'm using the MlBayesOpt package and the rf_opt function doesn't have a "formula" parameter:

```
rf_opt(train_data, train_label, test_data, test_label, num_tree = 500L,
  mtry_range = c(1L, ncol(train_data) - 1), min_node_size_range = c(1L,
  as.integer(sqrt(nrow(train_data)))), init_points = 4, n_iter = 10,
  acq = "ei", kappa = 2.576, eps = 0, optkernel = list(type =
  "exponential", power = 2))
```

Do you know any way of using the bayesian optimization after selecting the most important features?

Comment: It's very weird they don't keep the best model in rf_opt. They should use all the variables then. I think you just have to subset your train_data and test_data according to the what you want. and pull out "y" and input as test_label, train_label